# How to focus in WPF with WindowsFormHost

Tags: wpf, focus, winforms-interop

I have this simple setup:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="wpf1" PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="TextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus" />
    <TextBox Text="wpf2" PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="TextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus" />
    <WindowsFormsHost>
        <wf:TextBox Text="winforms" />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</StackPanel>

private void TextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Three textboxes, two WPF and one WinForm. I can't move focus between the two WPF-Textboxes which I desired but I can move focus to the WinForm-Textbox. The event `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` does not even triggered when moving from a WPF-Textbox to a WinForm-Textbox. Any clues to why and how this could be solved?

EDIT

I've noticed that `WindowsFormsHost.PreviewGotKeyboardFocus` is triggered first when focus is leaving the WindowsFormsHost again. Thats odd. Maybe it's a bug?